# PHP Ajax: live report of the PHP algorithm

Tags: php, ajax

If I have the next algorithm in the file **test.php**:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i)
{
     //Operations...
     ALERT_TO_MAIN_PAGE($i);
}
```

I call **test.php** with AJAX form the page **main.html**

How can I track the progress of `$i`, with live values?

So **main.html** will show like this, very time the PHP file has completed one iteration:

```
Done 0.
Done 1.
Done 2.
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [HTML5 Server Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) to send messages like that to the browser.

Right off [the website](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-server-code):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

/**
 * Constructs the SSE data format and flushes that data to the client.
 *
 * @param string $id Timestamp/id of this connection.
 * @param string $msg Line of text that should be transmitted.
 */
function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

$serverTime = time();

sendMsg($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()));
```

Comment: @GuyDavid no problem ^_^ happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way, because ajax waits for the operation to complete on the php side.

You should run your php offline (in background) and use ajax to simply ask for state (i.e. read info about progress from session).

Comment: It isn't cross browser - only HTML 5 solution.